# Git does not detect folder named with "icon"

Tags: git

In my git repository, I have folder name `icon` folder but git does not track the folder. I have created a new folder with same content named `icons` and it works fine. Here is the screenshot:

[image: Screenshot]

I am using MacOS and `git version 2.10.1 (Apple Git-78)`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Git doesn't track directories. Maybe check your `.gitignore` file where png files are mentioned to be ignored.

Or maybe check the ignored files like this

`git status --ignored`

Or maybe check if those files are excluded in `~/.gitconfig`.

Comment: Thanks @coderredoc This is strange that When I run `git status --ignored` then I see the icon folder is ignored. In my .gitignore file, I just have two lines that is

`.idea/
node_modules/`

That's all. Also in ~/.gitconfig is fine. so why the icon folder is ignored?

Comment: @Jewel.: Maybe you have excluded them from tracking? Sometimes these large sized files are excluded by us. Check that once.